# Equilibrium Points for 8th Degree Polynomial

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, roots

I have an 8th degree polynomial that I need the zeros for. Is there even a way to explicitly solve one? Its for a diff equations review. I need to sketch the phase line, which is a breeze once I get these points.

Comment: Whether or not there's a way to solve this depends on the equation...

Comment: draw a careful graph of the function, this will give you a good idea where the (real valued) roots lie. http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: (y^8)+(3y^6)+(y^4)+(y^2)-1=0

Comment: This one is solvable: setting $t=y^2$, it boils down to the quartic equation: $t^4+3t^3+t^2+t-1=0$, which can be solved by *Ferrari's method*, but it is not so simple as a quadratic equation…

Comment: The polynomial has exactly two real roots, a $\pm$ pair since it is strictly increasing for $y > 0$ but symmetric in $y.$

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $f(y)=y^8+3y^6+y^4+y^2-1$ has the following eight complex roots:
\begin{align}
y&=0.528895152153 + 0.77514139686\cdot i, \\
y&=0.528895152153 - 0.77514139686\cdot i, \\
y&=1.67802753513\cdot i,\\
y&= - 1.67802753513\cdot i, \\
y&= - 0.528895152153 + 0.77514139686\cdot i,\\
y&= - 0.528895152153 - 0.77514139686\cdot i,\\
y&=0.676760382226,\\
y&= - 0.676760382226.
\end{align}